# Canvas overlapping images reversing order

Tags: javascript, html, image, html5-canvas

When I draw on my HTML5 canvas with this code:

```
<canvas id="game">Your browser can't use canvas</canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var a = new Image();
a.onload = function() {
ctx.drawImage(a,50,40,50,50);
}
a.src = "image1.png";
var b = new Image();
    b.onload = function() {
ctx.drawImage(b,50,60,50,50);
}
b.src = "image2.png";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Image2.png appears on top of Image1.png.
However, after I reload the page, the images reverse order.
Also, sometimes on the first load (not reload) Image1.png appears on top of image2.

If I draw the images two times but in the same order (Image1 then Image2) after 2 reloads the images change order.

I am using Firefox 59.0.3 64 bit on a Windows 8.

Is this a problem with my code or is it a bug in Firefox?

Comment: It's a problem with your code. You don't have any synchronization logic for your two asynchronous callbacks, which introduces a race condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you cannot control the order of when the onload event will fire. The simplest way to correct this without changing your code too much (if I were you I would attach the same onload function and use wrapper around to encapsulate your variables):

```
<canvas id="game">Your browser can't use canvas</canvas>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById('game');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var counter = 2;
var a = new Image();
a.onload = function() {
counter--;
if(!counter) {
    ctx.drawImage(a,50,40,50,50);
    ctx.drawImage(b,50,60,50,50);
}
}
a.src = "image1.png";
var b = new Image();
    b.onload = function() {
counter--;
if(!counter) {
    ctx.drawImage(a,50,40,50,50);
    ctx.drawImage(b,50,60,50,50);
}
}
b.src = "image2.png";
</script>
</body>
</html>
```